# SSMS 2016 CTP3.1 November Preview (v13.0.800.111) bug? properties error: missing column federated_service_account

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2016

Using SSMS 2016 CTP3.1 November Preview (v13.0.800.111) on my laptop, whenever I right click any database object (the database, a table, etc.) I get the below error.

> ### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
>
> Cannot show requested dialog.
>
> ---
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> ### Cannot show requested dialog. (SqlMgmt)
>
> Attempt to retrieve data for object failed for Server ''.  >(Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)
>
> For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=13.0.800.111+((SQL_Main).151121-1556)&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Attempt+to+retrieve+data+for+object+Server&LinkId=20476
>
> ---
>
> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

---

> **Invalid column name 'federated_service_account'.
>   Invalid column name 'federated_service_account'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 207)**
>
> For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&ProdVer=13.00.0700&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=207&LinkId=20476
>
> ---
>
> BUTTONS:
>
> ### OK

I was able to run a Profiler trace to determine the query that's being run to throw this error:

```
SELECT
eds.location AS [RemoteDataArchiveEndpoint],
eds.name AS [RemoteDataArchiveLinkedServer],
rdad.remote_database_name AS [RemoteDatabaseName],
rdad.federated_service_account AS [RemoteDataArchiveUseFederatedServiceAccount],
case when rdad.federated_service_account = 1 then null else cred.name end AS [RemoteDataArchiveCredential]
FROM
sys.remote_data_archive_databases rdad
INNER JOIN sys.external_data_sources eds ON rdad.data_source_id = eds.data_source_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.database_scoped_credentials cred ON eds.credential_id = cred.credential_id
```

Anyone recognize this query? Where is it coming from, what's the source? Anyone else experiencing a similar error? Is this an SSMS bug?

Some interesting repro notes:

- This error happens while connecting from my laptop to the database that's on a VM in my organization.
- While RDP'd in to the VM and running SSMS locally on the VM and connecting to localhost, the error does not repro.
- The SSMS version on the VM (v13.0.700.242) is lower than the SSMS version on my laptop (v13.0.800.111). Hence, I'm afraid to update the SSMS on the VM to latest version as this error might throw there too.
- Running the profiler trace directly on the VM and doing the repro steps does not generate the same SQL that the newer SSMS version seems to generate from my laptop.

Comment: What is the version of the database engine you are connecting to? Is it box or cloud? During the CTP period because DMVs are changing it is probably best to keep everything at the same version. And if you're installing the CTPs, there is no reason to install the updates of SSMS from the web - they're the same builds as what you get in the CTP (e.g. the November update has the same SSMS that is in CTP 3.1, the October update had the same SSMS that was in CTP 3.0, etc). They're released on the same schedule.

Comment: The VM in question is running engine 13.0.700. The VM is one of the auto-generated ones in Azure for evaluation and testing, but captured and downloaded to be run on-prem. The SSMS on my laptop was installed after the VM was setup, so the VM is running October's build (CTP 3.0 / v13.0.700.242), while my laptop is running only SSMS November build (CTP 3.1 / v13.800.111) and no engine.

Comment: Additionally, is it possible to "downgrade" my laptop's SSMS from v13.0.800.111 to v13.0.700.242 to match the VM?

Comment: No, you can't downgrade SSMS. You could uninstall and reinstall the older version. Otherwise you'll need to either wait for the December update (which may have the same problem) or use the VM's local copy of SSMS. You could also generate a new Azure VM which, right now, should create 13.0.801, not 13.0.700, and your local copy of SSMS should work fine with that.

Comment: Thanks Aaron for your thoughts. Any ideas as to the source of the query? You alluded to a DMV, any idea which DMV?

Comment: The source of the query is from Object Explorer. I meant that it is querying DMVs and catalog views that are changing because the CTP is being actively developed, and the UI is not always in lock step with that development. That's why it's beta. :-)

Comment: Perhaps upgrading the VM's engine version is the way to resolve this. Is that as simple as getting the latest .ISO for SQL 2016 CTP and running the installer to upgrade?

Comment: I think so, but not sure, I haven't played with any of those Azure VM images yet...

Comment: This looks like an engine vs SSMS SMO version mismatch bug. Yes, you can download CTP 3.1 to the VM and upgrade the engine so it's in-sync with your local SSMS version.

Comment: The December preview release of SSMS (and the client tools shipping with the CTP 3.2 installation files) has resolved this issue entirely. [Or so say the release notes, at least](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/mt588477.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating the VM's engine to CTP 3.1 resolved the issue. I no longer get the error on my laptop's SSMS.